# displaying last 30 days with data from table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, zend-framework

I have a table of records that has a column with the created_date. I am looking for a way to display these records by date broke out in day sections. So Today would show only records that were added today and then underneath that table that shows yesterday with only yesterdays records. I am sure it is an array of some sort and may be simpler than i am making it out to be but i have looked at some loops and  cant piece it together. Tried this but not sure how to use it to populate the records.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; i++)
{
$timestamp = time();
$tm = 86400 * $i; // 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400 = 1 day in seconds
$tm = $timestamp - $tm;

$the_date = date("m/d/Y", $tm);
}
```

also since written in Zend i need proper stuff in the controller, model, view. I think the view is what i am stuck on. the model is just going to retrieve data by date. 
 Thanks for the help!

Updated 10:27 9-25-2012
This is the controller for the view

```
    public function detailsAction() 
{
    $request   = $this->getRequest();
    $setId     = $request->getParam('set_id');
    $pageIndex = $request->getParam('page_index', 1);
    $perPage = 15;
    $offset  = ($pageIndex - 1) * $perPage;

    $conn = XXX_Db_Connection::factory()->getSlaveConnection();
    $setDao  = XXX_Model_Dao_Factory::getInstance()->setModule('media')->getSetDao();
    $photoDao = XXX_Model_Dao_Factory::getInstance()->setModule('media')->getPhotoDao();
    $setDao->setDbConnection($conn);
    $photoDao->setDbConnection($conn);

    $set = $setDao->getById($setId);
    if (null == $set) {
        throw new XXX_Exception_NotFound();
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of photo that belongs to this set
     */
    $photos       = $photoDao->getPhotosInSet($setId, $offset, $perPage, true);
    $numPhotos = $photoDao->countPhotosInSet($setId, true);

    /**
     * Paginator
     */
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new XXX_Utility_PaginatorAdapter($photos, $numPhotos));
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($pageIndex);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($perPage);

    $this->view->assign('set', $set);
    $this->view->assign('photos', $photos);

    $this->view->assign('paginator', $paginator);
    $this->view->assign('paginatorOptions', array(
        'path'     => $this->view->url($set->getProperties(), 'media_set_details'),
        'itemLink' => 'page-%d',
    ));
}
```

here are the associated models

```
    public function getById($id) 
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set 
                    WHERE set_id = '%s'
                    LIMIT 1", 
                    mysql_real_escape_string($id));
    $rs  = mysql_query($sql);
    $return = (0 == mysql_num_rows($rs)) ? null : new Media_Models_Set(mysql_fetch_object($rs));
    mysql_free_result($rs);
    return $return;
}

    public function getPhotosInSet($setId, $offset = null, $count = null, $isActive = null)
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_photo AS f
                    INNER JOIN " . $this->_prefix . "media_photo_set_assoc AS fs
                        ON fs.photo_id = f.photo_id AND fs.set_id = '%s'",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($setId));
    if (is_bool($isActive)) {
        $sql .= sprintf(" WHERE f.is_active = '%s'", (int)$isActive);
    }
    $sql .= " ORDER BY f.photo_id DESC";
    if (is_int($offset) && is_int($count)) {
        $sql .= sprintf(" LIMIT %s, %s", $offset, $count);
    }

    $rs   = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    mysql_free_result($rs);
    return new XXX_Model_RecordSet($rows, $this);
}

public function countPhotosInSet($setId, $isActive = null)
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_photos FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_photo AS f
                    INNER JOIN " . $this->_prefix . "media_photo_set_assoc AS fs
                    ON fs.photo_id = f.photo_id AND fs.set_id = '%s'",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($setId));
    if (is_bool($isActive)) {
        $sql .= sprintf(" WHERE f.is_active = '%s'", (int)$isActive);
    }
    $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
    $rs   = mysql_query($sql);
    $row  = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
    mysql_free_result($rs);
    return $row->num_photos;
}
```

Updated 09/26/2012 - Added new method

I have added this to my view it displays the date as headers like i want however it prints duplicates also. I am looking to group them under the date:

This is the view:

```
<?php if ($this->sets) : ?>
<div class="t_media_list_sets">
<h2><?php echo $this->translator()->widget('title'); ?></h2>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->sets as $set) : ?>
    <?php $curDate = 0; ?>
    <?php $date = $set->created_date; ?>
    <?php if ($date != $curDate) : ?>
        <?php $curDate = $date; ?>
        <?php echo  $curDate; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url($set->getProperties(), 'media_set_details'); ?>">
            <?php echo $set->title; ?>
        </a>
        <?php echo $set->description; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the model i am using: Ignore previous models shown, i created a widget

```
    public function setlist($offset = null, $count = null, $exp = null) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set AS s";
    if ($exp) {
        $where = array();

        if (isset($exp['created_user_id'])) {
            $where[] = sprintf("s.created_user_id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($exp['created_user_id']));
        }
        if (isset($exp['keyword'])) {
            $where[] = "s.title LIKE '%" . addslashes($exp['keyword']) . "%'";
        }
        if (isset($exp['is_active'])) {
            $where[] = sprintf("s.is_active = '%s'", (int)$exp['is_active']);
        }

        if (count($where) > 0) {
            $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
        }
    }
    $sql .= " ORDER BY s.created_date DESC";
    if (is_int($offset) && is_int($count)) {
        $sql .= sprintf(" LIMIT %s, %s", $offset, $count);
    }

    $rs   = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    mysql_free_result($rs);
    return new XXX_Model_RecordSet($rows, $this);
}
```

Comment: What type of database object are you working with, its impossible to test what you need in this case without that and its structure.

Comment: Added to post with model and controller.

Comment: Why are you writing your own, insecure queries? Zend_Db is there for that purpose.

Comment: Not sure i know what you mean. The query is in a model - that is supposed to be the way it is. Separate from the view. How can it be insecure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research and some examples on the web i have gotten this to work. Same model as above but changed the view to this:

```
<?php $prevDate = 0; ?>


<?php if ($this->sets) : ?>
<div class="t_media_list_sets">
<h2><?php echo $this->translator()->widget('title'); ?></h2>
<dl>
<?php foreach ($this->sets as $set) : ?>
<?php $date = date('y-m-d', strtotime($set->created_date)); ?>
<?php $theDate = $date ?>
<!-- Date changed -->
<?php if ($theDate != $prevDate) : ?>
    <?php if(!empty($prevDate)): ?>
    <?php  echo '</dl>'; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <!-- Open new list -->
  <?php echo '<dl>'; ?>
  <!-- Show definition term for the group of events -->
  <?php echo '<dt>'; ?>
    <?php echo $theDate ?>
    <?php echo '</dt>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- Display current event -->
<?php echo '<dd>'; ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $this->url($set->getProperties(), 'media_set_details'); ?>">
        <?php echo $set->title; ?>
    </a>
    <?php echo $set->description; ?>
<?php echo '</dd>'; ?>

<!-- Remember date from previous row -->
<?php $prevDate = $theDate; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- Close last definition list -->
<?php echo '</dl>'; ?>    

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I will have to do some fine tuning with the layout but the principal is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
$d = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) 
    $d[] = date("d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
?>
```

Also Refer this link for such type of operations

http://www.vision.to/how-to-add-days-weeks-months-to-any-date-.php

Comment: The question still remains - how to use this in the view and populate the records from the table for those dates.

Comment: You can create tables dynamically and have this array as vaues in it

Answer (score 1):

Easier...

```
for( $i=1; $i<31; $i++ )
{
  $the_date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("-".$i." days"));
}
```

Comment: The question still remains - how to use this in the view and populate the records from the table for those dates.

Answer (score 1):

Well my simple suggestion will be restricting the data into mysql itself first by filtering it by date. Ex: created_date >= ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) and created_date <= CURRENT_DATE(),
order by created_date desc.

then when u retrieve it in php, u can filter it with the flag, 
last_date = ''
check if the current date in the row is not the same as last_date,
pickup another array / group display and start printing / functioning.

This should solve your issue much easier and simpler pattern.

Comment: So if i am reading this correctly i need to filter the table by date in the table itself? Or does this go in the model? Also "last_date" are you referring to what i have as the_date at the top? Could you possibly show me an array example of what you are referring too.